# nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate resultclass

Tags: spring, spring-boot

what is wrong ?

```
public List < ReportDTO> listProductAll() {
    String sql 
            = "select "
            + "ip.product_name as productName, "
            + "ip.base_price as basePrice, "
            + "iu.username as username "
            + "from tb_buy a  "
            + "left join in_product ip on a.id_product = ip.product_id "
            + "left join im_users iu on a.id_user = iu.user_id ";
    Query q = identifyServer.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql)
            .addScalar("productName")
            .addScalar("basePrice")
            .addScalar("username")
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ReportDTO.class));
    return q.list();
}

public class ReportDTO {

    private String productName;
    private Double basePrice;
    private String username;

    public ReportDTO(String productName, Double basePrice, String username) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.basePrice = basePrice;
        this.username = username;
    }
// getter setter
```

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not instantiate resultclass: ReportDTO; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate resultclass: ReportDTO

solve
public ReportDTO() {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate requires all entities to have a default no args constructor.
If your entity class doesn't have it, or if it's not public, you'll get this exception.